# What does it mean "Das Bisschen" in the given sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've encountered the following sentence spoken from man to a woman (probably wife):

> Jetzt reg dich doch nicht auf. Das Bisschen, es ist halb so wild!

I know that it means.

> Don't you be mad. ???, it is not so bad!

I know also that the "Bisschen" means "a little" e.g. (a classic one)

> Ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsch.

which is translated to:

> I speak German a little.

Is it some kind of a name that you are giving to the beloved one?

Comment: It simply means "Oh, that little bit", i.e. it tries to downplay the size of what bothered the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Caps in German mean some word is made into a substantive. They don't mean some word is a proper noun as in English.

> das Bisschen

*the small amount/this small amount*

The *das* in your example is used as a demonstrative pronoun. It refers to the small amount of something not mentioned in your example, which isn't a reason to get angry. By the way, the phrase

> halb so wild

means

*no reason to get angry*

in reality.

Comment: The sentence comes from the sketch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYK7BvRHfL8 . The guy is pissing in the garden. So your answer means that it means. "A little amount (in this context a piss in the garden) is no reason to get angry" ?

Comment: Correct. That's why it is always repeated throughout the sketch.

Comment: Also danke schön :)

Comment: It might have been intended as a pun *bisschen* vs. *Piss-chen*; in some dialects the difference can't hardly be heard.

Comment: *A little amount*? What is wrong with the literal translation *a little bit*?

Comment: It doesn't fit into the context well.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Also _a little bit_ is the literal translation of _ein bisschen_, not of _das Bisschen_.

Comment: Btw. is that "das bisschen" (so specification about what) part always mandatory if we want to use "halb so wild"?

Comment: @Janka: assuming you were replying to me: I think it does. *A little amount* sounds artificial, as if taken from a dictionary.

Comment: @sgf: Yes, and *that little bit* is the translation of *das Bisschen*. <shrug>

Comment: @Kamil: no, it isn't. But something that tries to downplay what happened should be expected in the same context. "Das Biscchen" also tries to downplay what happened, i.e. "it is not that big (a deal)".

Comment: One could also translate it as "no big deal", both *halb so wild* and *das Bisschen*.